# VBA Opening File error

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro on my workbook named CTAttendanceProgram.  In my code, I am attempting to open an additional workbook using the browse function.  I would like to place Sheet1 of this additional file after the sheet "Employee Data" in the original "CTAttendanceProgram".  Here is my code so far:

```
Dim fn
fn = Application.GetOpenFilename
If fn = False Then
    MsgBox "Nothing Chosen"
    Exit Sub
Else
    Workbooks.Open (fn)
    Workbooks("CTAttendanceProgram.xlsm").Activate
End If

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Worksheets("Recent Attendance").Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = Trueppl

Workbooks(fn).Sheets(1).Copy After:=Workbooks("CTAttendanceProgram.xlsm").Sheets("Employee Data")
Sheets(4).Name = "Recent Attendance"
```

Previously, I was using this code to open a pre-determined file and it worked just fine.  However, now that I'm using the browse function (yet still opening the same file), I am running into an error on the "Workbooks(fn).Sheet(1).Copy..." (second to last) line).  Any tips/suggestions?  Thanks in advance for any support.

Answer (score 1):

because fn is used to define the File path & File name it can not be used as a workbook.

do the following:

```
Dim fn
Dim wb As Workbook

fn = Application.GetOpenFilename
If fn = False Then
    MsgBox "Nothing Chosen"
    Exit Sub
Else
    Workbooks.Open (fn)
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Workbooks("CTAttendanceProgram.xlsm").Activate
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Worksheets("Recent Attendance").Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    wb.Sheets(1).Copy After:=Workbooks("CTAttendanceProgram.xlsm").Sheets("Employee Data")
    Sheets(4).Name = "Recent Attendance"
    wb.Close False
End If
```

Comment: Thanks!  However, I tried this code out an was getting an error when I set wb_name = ActiveWorkbook.Name.  Any idea what this could be caused by?

Comment: my mistake i adjusted the code in the anwser now. used activeworkbook.name to check correctness. it had to be ofcourse set wb = ActiveWorkbook

Comment: I appreciate your help, but the code still isn't working for me.  I am running into the same problem I had before, where it has a type mismatch error on the line where I copy the new sheet into the CTAttendance Workbook.  I'm not sure what is wrong, as all of the datatypes seem correct and I can't spot any misspelled functions.

Comment: sorry m8, my bad again >.< if you set wb as workbook no need to do workbook(wb) as wb is the workbook. Knew it just forgot to pay attention to it properly.